# Problema con formulario, Window Builder Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

Estoy intentando crear un formulario para dar de alta a un usuario utilizando el plugin Window Builder con Eclipse, compila pero a la hora de introducir los datos y darle al boton "dar de alta" salen todos los errores.
El programa si compila, pero al abrir la ventana y darle al boton no funciona y aparecen errores en la consola.

EDIT: Me aparecen todos estos errores.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Formulario$3.actionPerformed(Formulario.java:100)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)




import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import java.awt.Choice;

public class Formulario {

   private JFrame frame;
   private JTextField textField_Nombre;//cliclderecho refactor rename
   private JTextField textField_Apellido1;
   private JTextField textField_1_Apellido2;
   private JTextField textField_2_Telefono1;
   private JTextField textField_3_DNI;
   private JTextField textField_4_email;
   private JTextField textField_5_direccion;
   private JTextField textField_6_fecha;
   private JTextField textField_7_facebook;
   private JTextField textField_8_Numerodecuenta;
   private JTextField textField_9_Estudios;
   private JTextField textField_10_Telefono2;
   private JRadioButton rdbtnPremium;
   private JTextField textField_10_EstadoCivil;
   private JTextField textFielddia;
   private JTextField textFieldmes;
   private JTextField textFieldano;
   private Choice choice;
   private GestorUsuarios usuarios;
   private JButton btnNewButton;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GestorUsuarios gestor = new GestorUsuarios();

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Formulario window = new Formulario(gestor);
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Formulario(GestorUsuarios gestor) {
    this.usuarios = gestor;
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 487, 401);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][98.00,grow][70.00][pref!,grow][]", "[][][][][][][][][][][][]"));


    rdbtnPremium = new JRadioButton("Premium"); // Bloquea los campos que no pertecen a premium
    frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnPremium, "cell 2 0");
        rdbtnPremium.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField_7_facebook.setEnabled(true);
                textField_10_EstadoCivil.setEnabled(true);
                textField_9_Estudios.setEnabled(true);
                textField_10_EstadoCivil.setEnabled(true);
                textField_8_Numerodecuenta.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, "cell 1 10");  

        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int telefono1 = Integer.parseInt(textField_2_Telefono1.getText());
        int telefono2 = Integer.parseInt(textField_10_Telefono2.getText());
        int dia = Integer.parseInt(textFielddia.getText());
        int mes = Integer.parseInt(textFieldmes.getText());
        int ano = Integer.parseInt(textFieldano.getText());

        if (rdbtnPremium.isSelected()) {


            Premium Premium = new Premium(textField_Nombre.getText(), textField_Apellido1.getText(), textField_1_Apellido2.getText(),
                    textField_3_DNI.getText(), textField_4_email.getText(), 
                    dia, mes, ano, 
                    textField_8_Numerodecuenta.getText(), 
                    telefono2);


                    usuarios.alta(Premium);
        } else {


            Free Free = new Free(textField_Nombre.getText(),
                    textField_Apellido1.getText(),
                    textField_1_Apellido2.getText(), 
                    telefono1, textField_3_DNI.getText(), 
                    textField_4_email.getText(), textField_5_direccion.getText(),
                    dia, mes, ano, 
                    choice.getSelectedItem()
                    );


            usuarios.alta(Free);
            };
    }

});

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Nombre* ");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, "cell 0 1,alignx trailing");

    textField_Nombre = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_Nombre, "cell 1 1,growx");
    textField_Nombre.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_9 = new JLabel("Facebook");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_9, "cell 2 1,alignx center");

    textField_7_facebook = new JTextField();
    textField_7_facebook.setEnabled(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_7_facebook, "cell 3 1,growx");
    textField_7_facebook.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Apellido1*");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1, "cell 0 2,alignx trailing");

    textField_Apellido1 = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_Apellido1, "cell 1 2,growx");
    textField_Apellido1.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_10 = new JLabel("Numero de Cuenta*");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_10, "cell 2 2,alignx trailing");

    textField_8_Numerodecuenta = new JTextField();
    textField_8_Numerodecuenta.setEnabled(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_8_Numerodecuenta, "cell 3 2,growx");
    textField_8_Numerodecuenta.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Apellido2*");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2, "cell 0 3,alignx trailing");

    textField_1_Apellido2 = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1_Apellido2, "cell 1 3,growx");
    textField_1_Apellido2.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_11 = new JLabel("Estudios");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_11, "cell 2 3,alignx center");

    textField_9_Estudios = new JTextField();
    textField_9_Estudios.setEnabled(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_9_Estudios, "cell 3 3,growx");
    textField_9_Estudios.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Telefono");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3, "cell 0 4,alignx center");

    textField_2_Telefono1 = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2_Telefono1, "cell 1 4,growx");
    textField_2_Telefono1.setColumns(10);


    JLabel lblNewLabel_12 = new JLabel("Telefono*");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_12, "cell 2 4,alignx center");

    textField_10_Telefono2 = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_10_Telefono2, "cell 3 4,growx");
    textField_10_Telefono2.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("DNI*");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_4, "cell 0 5,alignx center");

    textField_3_DNI = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_3_DNI, "cell 1 5,growx");
    textField_3_DNI.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_13 = new JLabel("Estado Civil");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_13, "cell 2 5,alignx trailing");

    textField_10_EstadoCivil = new JTextField();
    textField_10_EstadoCivil.setEnabled(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_10_EstadoCivil, "cell 3 5,growx");
    textField_10_EstadoCivil.setColumns(10);


    JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("Email*");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_5, "cell 0 6,alignx center");

    textField_4_email = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_4_email, "cell 1 6,growx");
    textField_4_email.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_6 = new JLabel("Dirección");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_6, "cell 0 7,alignx trailing");

    textField_5_direccion = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_5_direccion, "cell 1 7,growx");
    textField_5_direccion.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_7 = new JLabel("Fecha*");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_7, "cell 0 8,alignx center,growy");

    textField_6_fecha = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_6_fecha, "cell 1 8,growx");
    textField_6_fecha.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_8 = new JLabel("Sexo");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_8, "cell 0 9,alignx center");

    choice = new Choice();
    frame.getContentPane().add(choice, "cell 1 9,alignx left,aligny center");
    choice.add("...");
    choice.add("Hombre");
    choice.add("Mujer");
    choice.add("Otro");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A que te referis con "salen todos los errores"? Tira alguna excepción? No compila el programa antes de correr? Por favor se mas específico en tu pregunta.

Comment: Amigo edita tu pregunta y si puedes publica el error que te sale.